# jsqmessagviewController time not display in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am making a chat app and in this, I used jsqmessageviewcontroller for display chat but faced one issue in chat first item is attachment like image,pdf etc then time not display. if the first item is text then time display properly. So anyone has an idea then please help me.
For attachment used custom cells.[image]

For timestamp display used below method:-

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, attributedTextForCellTopLabelAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSAttributedString?
{

    let message = self.messages[indexPath.item]
    let messageVMObj = MessageViewModal(withMessage: message)
    if(indexPath.item == 0){
        print("indexPath.item == 0 called")
        return messageVMObj.setDay()
    } else {
        let currentMessage = self.messages[indexPath.item]
        let previousMessage = self.messages[indexPath.item - 1]
        if DateExtension().compareDates(currentDate: currentMessage.date, previousDate: previousMessage.date)
        {
            return nil
        }
        else
        {
          return messageVMObj.setDay()
        }
    }
}


 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout, heightForCellTopLabelAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    let message = self.messages[indexPath.item]
    let messageVMObj = MessageViewModal(withMessage: message)

    //set height for group Msg Tag
    if isGroup {
        let msg = self.messages[indexPath.item]
        if  msg.gpMessageType != "" {
            return 0.0
        }
    }

    if(indexPath.item == 0){
        return 20.0
    } else {
        let currentMessage = self.messages[indexPath.item]
        let previousMessage = self.messages[indexPath.item - 1]
        if DateExtension().compareDates(currentDate: currentMessage.date, previousDate: previousMessage.date)
        {
           return 0.0
        }
        else
        {
            return 20.0
        }
    }


}
```

So if any solution for that then please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Either your implementation of custom cells is lacking parent `super` calls leading to no top label display or your `isGroup` variable is wrong somehow. Can you share your custom cell implementation ?